# contact recruiter who told will get back to me

Tags: job-search, recruitment

I was told by a recruiter that I would be receiving a call back from her in November for the next round of my technical interview.

Now, it is almost end of November and I want to contact her. I am not really sure how should I phrase my email. Or, should I wait for some more time till the end of November month to contact her?

Comment: Wait until the end of november.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks. If I don't hear back from her after November, How should I phrase my email?

Comment: Possibly phrasing it on tips for how to improve next time you have an interview? I would phrase it as if I assume that I didn't get it, not she made a mistake etc... Putting yourself in the wrong can be safer IMOH.

Comment: @Tim, actually she told my next round of interview will be in November. I mean, from what I understood, she told am selected for next round but the call will happen only in November.

Comment: There is still 9 days left, I think wait until the end of monday. That leaves a week for her to organise everything - maybe there have been some delays? I think 1 week from being told about an interview to the date is reasonable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask for an update and if there was any feedback on the interview. That would be my suggestion for phrasing it, especially if the initial interview was more than a week ago. The tone I would aim is that, "Hey, I was wondering if you had some news for me..." so that it is just a bit of a general message wondering if there is anything new. If the interview was a day or two ago, I would wait another week before sending this e-mail as you want there to be enough time that you waited patiently in a sense.

---

Yes, you would be responding to the last e-mail in the chain so that she knows what this would be in regards to you asking. If you feel it necessary you could say, "We are 2/3rds through November now and I just wondered if you could give me an update here," though some may see that as being a bit analytical in the e-mail.

Comment: Thanks. But I have the email exchange with me and the final email says to wait for her email in November. Basically, the email says "I will contact you in November and your next step would be an onsite interview". So, can I just email her saying "Is there any update?" over that email chain itself?

Answer (score 1):

**Never let a recruiter control your interview process** because:

1. While they like to make you think you are the customer, you are not. The employer is the customer - they are the people paying the recruiter, not you.
2. The recruiter is likely juggling dozens of candidates for several jobs. They may be too busy to get back to you.
3. The employer may have changed their schedule, had their funding cut, been bought or gone through any combination of a myriad things that can effect hiring.

By all means, let the recruiter organize interviews and keep them up to date with any changes on your side but **do not wait for them to get back to you**.  Contact them as often as you feel you need to. I prefer the phone because you can get immediate feedback and hear the recruiters tone of voice.

Comment: thanks. So, the recruiter is a part of the company's hiring team I guess. So, does this apply to them as well?

Comment: Yes. In general, a recruiter's job is to find candidates to fill a position, not to find a position for a candidate. Recruiters, generally, are not bad people. They just have a different focus to what some candidates expect.